# Cómo separar el HTML incrustado de un código PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo este código que tiene HTML incrustado:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div>Error, el dominio debe ser @gmail.com</div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Y aunque funciona, **no logro separar el PHP del HTML** (porque mi idea es que el `<textarea>` y el `<div> de error` estén presentes desde que se cargue la página y no hasta que se haga el submit)

**He probado esto y recibo el error "Undefined variable":**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    foreach($res as $mcMails);
} else {
    echo '<div>Error, el dominio debe ser @gmail.com</div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">Total: <?php echo sizeof($res) ?></div>
        <textarea type="text"><?php echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

También probé separándolos en archivos distintos con `<?php include('archivo.php'); ?>` y `<?php require('archivo.php'); ?>` y me sale lo mismo de Variables indefinidas.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Ambos fragmentos están en un solo archivo (index.php). Ya probé con las formas que da php.net y no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Prueba a hacer lo que pretendes hacer de la forma más sencilla posible, eliminando todo el código que no sea estrictamente necesario para lo que buscas y modifica tu pregunta para que podamos entender qué necesitas y así ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo ese **div** se crea a partir de que se cumpla la condición **if** de PHP, para eso debes sacar de la condición de ese fragmento, ejemplo:

```js
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

echo '<div class="box">
           <div class="title">Total: 
              <textarea type="text">';

if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
  
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo '<div>Error, el dominio debe ser @gmail.com</div>';
}
echo '</textarea>
   </div>
</div>';

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>

<div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Dime si te funciono.